# How do i get value in a array from dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, web-services

am calling a web service from my ios app , it returned dictionary of dictionaries,, 
like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Business classification</key>
        <string>a:2:{i:0;s:19:"Broker - Securities";i:1;s:18:"Financial Services";}</string>
        <key>Cell phone</key>
        <string>(2201258886</string>
        <key>Company position</key>
        <string>First Vice President - Wealth Management, CFP?</string>
        <key>Country</key>
        <string>UNITED STATES of AMERICA</string>
        <key>Email</key>
        <string>ravikirans@ms.com</string>
        <key>Full name</key>
        <string>llndrees</string>
        <key>Office phone</key>
        <string>(707) 571-5761</string>
        <key>Rkkkty/name</key>
        <string>Santkkka Roskka</string>
        <key>State</key>
        <string>Cakklifornia</string>
        <key>user_id</key>
        <string>1</string>
    </dict>
    <key>10</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Business classification</key>
        <string>a:1:{i:0;s:16:"Business advisor";}</string>
        <key>Cell phone</key>
        <string>415-491-4102</string>
        <key>Company position</key>
        <string>Business Adviser</string>
        <key>Country</key>
        <string>UNITED STATES of AMERICA</string>
        <key>Email</key>
        <string>bygttfn@pacbgf</string>
        <key>Full name</key>
        <string>Biolas</string>
        <key>Office phone</key>
        <string>415+656165402</string>
        <key>Rotuhuhame</key>
        <string>Tiburon</string>
        <key>State</key>
        <string>Caliggggfornia</string>
        <key>user_id</key>
        <string>13</string>
    </dict>
```

now i need to get all emails in a array  how do i do this
i tried this

```
 NSDictionary * Usernames = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:strDocDirPath];


            NSLog(@"%@",[Usernames valueForKey:@"Email"]);
```

but its returning nil,,can anybody help me out pls

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like followings:

```
NSDictionary * Usernames = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:strDocDirPath];
    for (NSDictionary *item in Usernames)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[item valueForKey:@"Email"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be a step by step process,
try like this

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[Usernames valueForKey:@"first key"] valueForKey:@"second key"] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function of dictionary to enumerate and get all values of emails and store it into array.

> - (void)enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop))block